# Can't load Django static files in view

Tags: python, django

I'm a new player in Django and Python. I want to load the static files from the project level static folder. The problem is I can't but I still can load the static of an app.
This is the structure of my project:

```
Yaas
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
    templates
        base.html
    static
        style.css
    auction
        templates
            auction
                index.html
        static
            auction
                style.css
        __init__.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
```

The thing is it works with static file of auction, like this in base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'auction/style.css' %}" />
```

But it returns 404 with the project static file:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

I tried other solutions and document on Django but it still didn't work. I am using Django 1.10.

Comment: Those are not rendered by Django, so the tags won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this work by adding the following:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) (after point 4):

> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to
>   a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your
>   apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your
>   settings file where Django will also look for static files.

Please note that the `STATIC_ROOT` directory, where Django will output all collected static files found in each `<app>/static` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` directories, must be different.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works! Thank you. So it's like the STATIC_ROOT is not used in the new version of Django to include the project static files anymore?

Comment: It seems like STATIC_ROOT is used to indicate where the static files are collected (output) by Django (with the collectstatic command).Checking the docs, I don't think this should be removed but it should be different to the STATICFILES_DIRS directory. If they are both the same, Django can't replace the output STATIC_ROOT directory with all the collected static files as that directory also has the input static files. I'll adjust my answer